# Spell casting in Gringotts

Tags: harry-potter

In the movie *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2*, at the Lestranges' vault.

> **Harry:** Lumos.
>   *Their wands cast balls of light.*
>   **Hermione:** Accio Horcrux.
>   **Griphook:** No kind of magic would work in here.

If that is so, how the hell did Harry, Hermione, and Ron cast the spell *Lumos*, if no kind of magic would work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hmmm I think you must have misheard, the correct quote is

> Griphook: That kind of magic won't work in here.

[image]

(The above is a screenshot taken from my copy of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2* on DVD, with English subtitles turned on.)

So it's [as per the books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/145979/46027), you can certainly do magic in the Lestrange's vault, but you can't summon specific objects as an extremely straightforward way of circumventing the Gemino and Flagrante Curses, which are part of the protection.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that they used Lumos in the vault in the book, and it worked, but what Griphook says is not "*No kind of magic would work in here.*"

This is the relevant scene:

> “Accio Cup!” cried Hermione, who had evidently forgotten in her desperation what Griphook had told them during their planning sessions.
>
> “No use, no use!” snarled the goblin.

He is not saying that magic doesn't work in the vault, he is saying that **you cannot summon a Horcrux.**  This is further enforced many other times, including here:

> She raised her wand and said, “Accio Locket!”
>
> Nothing happened. Ron, who had been searching the folds of the faded curtains, looked disappointed.
>
> “Is that it, then? It’s not here?”
>
> “Oh, it could still be here, but under counter-enchantments,” said Hermione. “Charms to prevent it being summoned magically, you know.”

Many spells are used in Gringotts, including the Imperius Curse, Cushioning Charms, Confounds charms, etc. by the trio in that visit alone.  When Griphook says *"No kind of magic would work in here,*" I assume he means "*no magic like that works **on the Horcrux.***"

---

That all being said, the true reason for this problem is because the movies are nonsense.

Comment: oh. so the enchantment just works for the horcruxes. i must have read the 7th book, i only read the 1st to third. thanks!

Comment: I think so. There are a lot of information from the books that had been left out, particularly the apparition.

Comment: I don't think that Griphook knew the exact nature of the object they were searching for.  So his warning could not have been specific to horcruxes.

Comment: @TGnat As it says in the book, Griphook had told them before that they could not summon what was in the vault.  It is probably common for objects in the vaults to be enchanted like that.

Comment: How is Griphook saying "that you cannot summon a Horcrux"!? How the blazes would that goblin know about horcruxes, let alone that what the golden trio are looking for in the vault is a horcrux?

Comment: @GhotiandChips He is saying "You can't summon what is in the vault."  Presumably people's belongings in vaults have this kind of enchantment on them a lot.

Comment: Oh, I understand what the goblin means, but your answer literally says, "he is saying that you cannot summon a Horcrux.", so your answer implies a false assumption, that Griphook not only knows about Horcruxes in general, but that he knows the trio are looking for one in Bella's vault, which is absolute rubbish information. I'm critiquing the answer, the other one is better, in my opinion.

Comment: The correct answer is that "he is saying that you cannot summon items in a Gringotts vault". The assumption that Griphook's comment is in reference to Horcruxes only implies that he knows about Horcruxes and the trio's attempt to find one in the vault, which is rubbish.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Sure.